# How to access different resources of floorplan and save position of each resource in database

Tags: node.js, d3.js, interact.js

I am having an image of a floorplan like this

[image: Floor plan of office]

There are two things which I am looking

1. I am having the record in my database which tells the occupancy of each cabin or seat, whether it's occupied or not. So, I just want to reflect the occupancy of each seat/cabin in this picture.
2. When a user clicks on any seat/cabin I should be able to get the respective seat or cabin id.

Two achieve this, There are two approaches:

1. Either place a small colour full overlay on the seat which will show whether it's occupied or not.
2. Create a dynamic DOM version of this floorplan on the web and then access each resource.

Please help me with this, It's been weeks since I am struggling with this.

Thanks.

Comment: Go for the option 2

Comment: But I am not able to find a way to convert to that floor plan to dynamic DOM. Any open-source which can help me to segregate floor plan into further resources

Comment: What is your floor plan data format?

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky currently its in jpg. In which format should I get ?

Comment: I think SVG is far more convenient for your task